# writing a function that subtract one from string in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, math

I am learning C in school and am doing a project that involves writing a function(`str_subtract_one`) that gets a string containing a positive integer.

The function subtracts `1` from that integer and puts the obtained value in the string.

In the code below, I successfully wrote a function to do that, but the thing is that the input numbers may be larger than the maximum of `int`, `long` or `long long`, so I should not try to convert the string to an integer.

So, without converting the string into `int`, `long` or `long long`, how can I do the same job?

I appreciate any feedback. Thank you so much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void str_subtract_one(char* num) {
  
  char *end; // to use it in strtol function, 

  long long as_long = strtoll(num,&end,10);  //to convert string to long, use strtol.

 
  sprintf(num, "%lld", as_long - 1); // to convert long into string and now num has a string value

  
}

int main()  {

  char nums[] = "2462343434344545";
  
  str_subtract_one(nums);

  printf("\nstr_subtract_one function result; %s\n",nums);

  return 0;
}
```

For example if input string is `"2323"`, it should output `"2322"`.

If `"1000"`, output `"999"`, etc.

Comment: And if the string is "0" what is the result of subtracting?

Comment: Use what you learned in elementary school about the role of "place value" in representing numbers in base 10. Go digit by digit.  Write some code.

Comment: Hint.  It's a little easier if your function converts `"1000"` to `"0999"` with a leading zero.  If desired, you can trim the zero when you output.

Comment: You are not allowed to go online and ask others to solve the assignment for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following algorithm:

- If the last character of the string is a `'9'`, then you can change it to an `'8'`.
- Otherwise, if the last character of the string is a `'8'`, then you can change it to an `'7'`.
- Otherwise, if the last character of the string is a `'7'`, then you can change it to an `'6'`.
- [...]
- Otherwise, if the last character is a `'0'`, you change it to a `'9'` and repeat all of the above with the next digit.

If you run out of digits (which will happen if all of the digits are `'0'`), you must overwrite the entire string with the new string `"-1"`. This will only work if at least 3 bytes have been allocated for the string, otherwise there will be not enough room to write the result, without causing a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). For example, if you write

`char nums[] = "0";`

then trying to write `"-1"` into the string will write to the array out of bounds, causing [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) (your program may crash).

For this reason, you would have to write the following instead, if you want to ensure that there is room for writing `"-1"`:

`char nums[3] = "0";`

Note that this algorithm will only work with positive numbers. (In your question, you stated that we can assume that the numbers are positive.)

If you want it to also work with negative numbers, you must first check the sign of the number and then apply the appropriate algorithm. You will need one algorithm for handling positive numbers and one for handling negative numbers (although you may want to try to combine both of them into one algorithm).

In accordance with the [community guidelines on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471), I will not provide the full solution to your problem at this time. However, I can add code later, if required.

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback! I will try to write codes by myself.

Comment: @Andres Wenzel When it changes "1000" to "0999", how do you get rid of the first 0 so that the result would be "999"??

Comment: @HayatoKoyama: You could move all characters (including the terminating null character) by one place to the left, if you want to get rid of a leading zero. However, is it possible that the input can also contain leading zeroes? If so, do you want to remove them, too? In that case, it is possible that you have to remove more than one leading zero, so you may have to move all characters by more than one place.