# How to get rid of first element in a string in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, function

I am learning c and having difficulty on this problem.
I am writing a function that getsa string containing a positive integer.

The function subtracts 1 from that integer and puts the obtained value in the string.

But my problem right now is that

for example When the input is "1000", I want the output to be "999". Not "0999".
input "100" , I want the output to be "99", instead of "099". so I am going to just get rid of the first 0, at the end of this function.
How can I get rid of the first element of a string??

I appreciate any feedback! thank you so much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void str_subtract_one(char* num) {
  int len = 0;
  int i ;
  for (i=0; num[i]!='\0';i++){
    len++;


  }
  int j;
for (j = len;j !=0;j--){
  if (len != '0'){
    if (num[j-1]=='9'){
      num[j-1] = '8';
      break;
    }  
    else if (num[j-1]=='8'){
      num[j-1] = '7';
      break;
    }  
    else if (num[j-1]=='7'){
      num[j-1] = '6';
      break;
    }
    else if (num[j-1]=='6'){
      num[j-1] = '5';
      break;
    } 
    else if (num[j-1]=='5'){
      num[j-1] = '4';
      break;
    }
    else if (num[j-1]=='4'){
      num[j-1] = '3';  
      break;
    } 
    else if (num[j-1]=='3'){
      num[j-1] = '2';
      break;
    }  
    else if (num[j-1]=='2'){
      num[j-1] = '1';
      break;
    } 
    else if (num[j-1]=='1'){
      num[j-1] = '0';
      break;
    }
    else if (num[j-1]=='0'){
      num[j-1] = '9';
     
    }

  }
  
}    
  if (num[0] =='0')
  //I dont know how to get rid of the first 0 here.

   
 
}

int main()  {
  
  
  char nums[] = "10000";
  
  
  str_subtract_one(nums);

  printf("\nQ5\nstr_subtract_one function result; %s\n",nums);

  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than working with strings the whole way through, it will likely be a lot simpler to convert the string to an int, do math on the int, then convert back to string.

Comment: But note also that that big `if` ... `else` block is horrendous.  You need a special case for `'0'`, but for any and all of the other digits, `num[j-1] -= 1` will do the job.

Comment: Are you forbidden from using the libraries you're including?  `atoi` and `strnlen` could help you

Comment: Also `len != '0'` does not mean what you seem to think it means.  I presume that `len != 0`, which is different, is what you had in mind.

Comment: OP stated in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69366990/12149471) that the number may be larger than [`LLONG_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits), so they want to store the number as a string instead of as an integer type.

Comment: https://github.com/kokke/tiny-bignum-c

Comment: What's the expected outcome if you call it with `char nums[] = "0";`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I have addressed that issue in [my answer to OP's previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69367125/12149471). It was still appropriate that you raised that issue again, though.

Comment: You are not allowed to go online and ask others to solve the assignment for you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not allowed to use the stdlib functions.

You need to move all the chars one character to the left:

```
    if (num[0] =='0')
    {
        for(size_t i = 1; i <= len; i++)
        {
            num[i - 1] = num[i];
        }
    }
```

Or if you are allowed to use some standard library functions:

```
    if (num[0] =='0')
    {
        memmove(num, num + 1, len);
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Prbzj6b9a

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void str_subtract_one(char* num) {    
    int number;
    sscanf(num, "%d", &number);
    number--;
    sprintf(num, "%d", number);
}

int main(void) {
  char num[5] = "1000";
  str_subtract_one(num);
  printf("%s\n", num);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe he is not allowed to use this abstraction level functions

Comment: OP stated in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69366990/12149471) that the number may be larger than [LLONG_MAX](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits), so they need to store the number as a string instead of as an integer type. Therefore, this answer will probably not be useful to OP. Of course, this is not your fault, because OP should have mentioned this contraint in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the first character of the string just add 1 to the string pointer. Example:

```
puts("1234" + 1);
```

prints:

```
234
```

Note that this answer literally addresses the question in the topic.

Comment: According to [this previous question from OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69366990/12149471), it seems OP wants to change the original string in such a way that the leading zero gets removed.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, that is why I've added the note. The topic looks well defined but it is barely related to the actual problem. It should be something like "how to remove heading zeros?" or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void str_subtract_one(char *num) {
    int len = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; num[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        len++;                          // determine the number of digits
    }

    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {    // upward from the last digit
        if (num[i] == '0') {            // if the digit is '0'
            num[i] = '9';               // then put '9' and continue to the upper digit
        } else {                        // if the digit > '0'
            num[i]--;                   // then subtract 1
            break;                      // and exit the loop
        }
    }

    if (num[0] == '0' && len > 1) {     // if the highest digit is '0' and has lower digit
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {     // then shift the array including the terminating '\0'
            num[i] = num[i + 1];
        }
    }
}

int main()  {
    char nums[] = "10000";
    str_subtract_one(nums);
    printf("\nQ5\nstr_subtract_one function result; %s\n",nums);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A solution with minimal changes to your existing code:

```
char* str_subtract_one(char* num) {
  // as mentioned, this can be far more concise
  // ...

  // I dont know how to get rid of the first 0 here.

  // Advance the pointer past a leading zero.
  // If there's ever a case where there can be more than one leading '0',
  // you'll need to handle that here in a loop instead
  if (num[0] =='0')
  {
    num++;
  }

  return num;
}
 
int main()  {
  char nums[] = "10000";
  char* newNum = str_subtract_one(nums);

  // prints 9999
  printf("\nQ5\nstr_subtract_one function result; %s\n",newNum);

  return 0;
}
```

[example](https://godbolt.org/z/x3MseeP89)

Comment: Not the very best way of doing it.

Comment: @0___________ under what criteria? Faster than shifting every character left by one.

Comment: simply this pointer is not referencing the beginning of the object. It is a very common source of very difficult to debug problems in larger projects.

Comment: @0___________ speak for yourself. Think I've used `memmove` exactly once in my career. I'll choose zero-copy every time.

Comment: Well, the signature in the question returns void. This means you cannot return the pointer. You need to actually modify the string in place. In addition, if you simply lose your zero character that's a memory leak.

Comment: @IgorShinkar OP never made the stipulation the function prototype must be preserved. There is no dynamic memory allocation in OP or my answer, so no possibility for a memory leak, that has nothing to do with whether C strings are properly `NUL` terminated or not. If the `NUL` character is somehow lost that's a different problem entirely, not relevant at all.